# Assistance with SQL query - duplicate values

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following table:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymYRX.png

Notice that there are some customers that share the same invoice number.

I would like to have an SQL query which result displays the customers and invoices that are equal between customers.

I tried something like (of course it didn't work):

```
SELECT Customer, Invoice_Number, Invoice_Amount
FROM CUSTOMER_TABLE
WHERE (Customer = Fred)||Invoice_Number = (Customer = Alan)||Invoice_Number
```

Expected result would be:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGNF1.png

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.invoice_number = t.invoice_number and
                    t2.customer <> t.customer
             );
```

That is, show the invoices that have more than one customer on the invoice.

Comment: How would you add a new condition to this query, like the amount? where t.amount = 10 and exists (... bla bla...) ?

Comment: @FranJ . . . You could do that, but your comment suggests a *new* question.  If a simple `where` clause doesn't work, you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

Building this query is clearest to me by first finding all the Invoice Numbers that appear for more than 1 customer:

```
select Invoice_Number from CUSTOMER_TABLE 
group by Invoice_Number having count(*) > 1;

 Invoice_Number 
----------------
 AB111
```

Now, find every row containing one of those Invoice Numbers by using the query above in a `where` clause, for:

```
select * from CUSTOMER_TABLE 
where Invoice_Number in (
   select Invoice_Number from CUSTOMER_TABLE 
   group by Invoice_Number having count(*) > 1
);

 Customer | Invoice_Number
----------+---------------
 Fred     | AB111
 Fred     | AB111
 Alan     | AB111
 Alan     | AB111
 Alan     | AB111
```